# Обработка нажатия telegram кнопки?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Создал telegram бота, поставил Webhook, все работает. Сейчас пытаюсь сделать кнопки, кнопки должны обратиться к серверу и с моего сервера выполнить запрос по ссылке, т.е мне надо по клику на кнопку в телеграмме якобы перейти по ссылке, запустить действие. Пытаюсь выполнить все на PHP .Прощу прощение если запутано!

Comment: Слишком сложно. А что должно получиться в конечном итоге?

Comment: Не понятно что нужно, но подозреваю что можно через ajax отправить нужные данные на сервер.

Comment: В телеграме у бота планируется клавиатура, из трех кнопок, каждая кнопка должна как бы перейти по адресу типо "https://google.com", т.е обратится к нему, и после обращение бот ответит - "Запрос выполнен".
Я делал инлайн клавиатуру, и тестировал кнопку URL, но она мне не подходит так как она показывает предупреждение о переходе на сайт, а мне переходит и не надо на него, а просто выполнить запрос к этому адресу

Comment: Ну тогда по нажатию на кнопку дерни курлом например свой адрес из обработчика

Comment: Понимаю что curl должен быть тут, но вот как мне на кнопку в самом боте повесить обработчика не понимаю(

Comment: Тут сложнее. Я давно уже не работал с телеграмом. Могу посоветовать ютуб

Comment: примеры кода в студию, а лучше сразу минимальный самодостаточный пример кода, который не работает =)